# Collect a Stream of Map<K,V> to Map<K,List<V>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a `Stream< Map< K, V > >` and I'm trying to merge those maps together, but preserve duplicate values in a list, so the final type would be `Map< K, List<V> >`. Is there a way to do this? I know the `toMap` collector has a binary function to basically choose which value is returned, but can it keep track of the converted list?

i.e.

if `a` is a `Stream< Map< String, Int > >`

```
a.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()).collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (val1, val2) -> ??
);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-): see the javadoc, but in your case it should be something like that:

```
a.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
 .collect(
   Collectors.groupingBy(
     Map.Entry::getKey, 
     HashMap::new, 
     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())
   )
);
```

Or:

```
a.map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Set::stream)
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
     Map.Entry::getKey, 
     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())
   )
);
```

Comment: You can use [`groupingBy(Function, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and leave out `HashMap::new`. Also, for those who prefer method references, you can do `a.map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Set::stream)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit wordier than the groupingBy solution, but I just wanted to point out that it is also possible to use toMap (as you initially set out to do) by providing the merge function:

```
    a.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()).collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> { 
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(entry.getValue());
                    return list;
                },
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    list1.addAll(list2);
                    return list1;
                }));
```